# Get the highest but also unique number from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have a question. I'm looking for a way to get the higest unique number of an array.

```
var temp = [1, 8, 8, 8, 4, 2, 7, 7];
```

Now I want to get the output 4 since that is the unique highest number.

Is there a good & hopefully short way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is:

```
Math.max(...temp.filter(el => temp.indexOf(el) == temp.lastIndexOf(el)))
```

**Explanation:**

1. First, get the elements which are unique in the array using [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

   ```
   temp.filter(el => temp.indexOf(el) === temp.lastIndexOf(el)) // [1, 4, 2]
   ```
2. Now, get the max of the numbers from the array using ES6 [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

   ```
   Math.max(...array) // 4
   ```

   This code is equivalent to

   ```
   Math.max.apply(Math, array);
   ```

Comment: I don't think arrow functions have wide support across browsers yet. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: @NickT: Probably more than spread arguments… But it doesn't matter, OP tagged his question ES6 so I used it.

Comment: Am I mussing something. Because I get NaN.... I did ---> console.log(Math.max(temp.filter(el => temp.indexOf(el) == temp.lastIndexOf(el))));

Comment: @Romano: You're missing the `...`. See [Demo here](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&presets=es2015&experimental=false&loose=false&spec=false&code=var%20temp%20%3D%20%5B1%2C%208%2C%208%2C%208%2C%204%2C%202%2C%207%2C%207%5D%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(Math.max(...temp.filter((el%2C%20i)%20%3D%3E%20temp.indexOf(el)%20%3D%3D%20temp.lastIndexOf(el)))))

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to get fancy, you can use a sort and loop to check the minimal number of items:

```
var max = 0;
var reject = 0;

// sort the array in ascending order
temp.sort(function(a,b){return a-b});
for (var i = temp.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
  // find the largest one without a duplicate by iterating backwards
  if (temp[i-1] == temp[i] || temp[i] == reject){
     reject = temp[i];
     console.log(reject+" ");
  }
  else {
     max = temp[i];
     break;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the spread operator you can find the hightest number easily

```
Math.max(...numArray);
```

The only thing left then is to either filter duplicates from the array beforehand, or remove all the elements that match your maximum number if its a duplicate.

remove beforeHand would be easiest in es6 like this.

```
Math.max(...numArray.filter(function(value){ return numArray.indexOf(value) === numArray.lastIndexOf(numArray);}));
```

For a non es6 compatible way to remove duplicates have a look at [Remove Duplicates from JavaScript Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array), the second answer contains an extensive examinations of several alternatives

Comment: `Set` doesn't actually remove all elements that are non-unique, it only removes their duplicates so that one of each stays in the set. I think OP is expecting the result 4, not 8.